# can anybody find what wordpress theme this site use?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i tried to find the theme using online tools, although it detected that the site is using the WordPress,it doesn't help me to find exact name of the theme

can you find the WordPress theme of this site ?
http://jayabharathhomes.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That website is using **[Codeus Wordpress Theme from Themeforest](https://themeforest.net/item/codeus-multipurpose-responsive-wordpress-theme/6906054)**. I found it by viewing the web page source (see image below).

But there is no concrete rule in finding out a Wordpress theme used by a website. Sometimes, you can discover it by checking out the `<head>` part and looking for a loaded CSS file, usually named `style.css`, located at `wp-content/themes/theme_name`. If you can't find something like that, as in this case, then you will have to "dig further" in the web page source section.

[image]

Comment: i tried the same method to find the theme of this website http://alfakhamaholidays.com, i couldn;t find it

Comment: alfakhamaholidays.com is not using Wordpress framework. Try pasting that link here and see for yourself: http://guess.scritch.org